# Bootstrap confidence intervals: proving consistency

Tags: statistics, bootstrap-sampling

I am working on using a bootstrap technique to compute confidence intervals of a parameter of interest.

Let $\textbf{Z}_1, ... \textbf{Z}_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be an (iid) random sample. From this random sample, we compute $\hat{\theta}$ parameter (very ugly to express explicitly). I would like to obtain CI for this parameter.

I utilize the basic bootstrap technique. This involves randomly sampling, with replacement, from our random sample to generate multiple bootstrap samples, each matching the size of our original dataset. For each bootstrap sample, I calculate the estimate of the statistic $\hat{\theta}^\star$. Subsequently, we determine the $95%$-quantiles of the re-sampled statistics to derive the confidence intervals. I want to prove their asymptotic correctness. Is there some general result that I can use? I only found theoretical justification using Berry-Essen theorem for $\theta$=mean, but my statistic $\theta$ is much more complicated.

In summary, I want to prove something like this:

**Theorem**
Let $\hat{\theta}$ be an estimator (from a sample size $n$) of $\theta$ and let $\mathbb{E}||\textbf{Z}||^2<\infty$.

Denote the resamples from the original sample as $(\textbf{Z}^\star_{1,1}, \dots \textbf{Z}^\star_{1,n}),\dots, (\textbf{Z}^\star_{B,1}, \dots, \textbf{Z}^\star_{B,n})$, with corresponding estimates $\hat{\theta}_1^\star, \dots, \hat{\theta}_B^\star$ for $B\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $U:=\hat{\theta}_{(\alpha)}^\star$ represent the $B(1-\alpha)$ largest value out of  $\hat{\theta}_1^\star, \dots, \hat{\theta}_B^\star$.

Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{B\to\infty}P(\hat{\theta}<U) =\alpha. $$